# As the file is having blank lines and header, Code is failing with Nullexecptionerror

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing Map Reduce Program for the below problem statement -
As the file is having blank lines and header, Code is failing with `Nullexecptionerror`, Can you please check my code and let me know what is error

Fetch the record having `VendorID` as '2' AND `tpep_pickup_datetime` as '2017-10-01 00:15:30' AND `tpep_dropoff_datetime` as '2017-10-01 00:25:11' `AND` `passenger_count` as '1' `AND trip_distance as` '2.17'

Filter all the records having `RatecodeID` as 4.

Group By all the records based on payment type and find the count for each group. Sort the payment types in ascending order of their count.

Sample Data :

```
endorID,tpep_pickup_datetime,tpep_dropoff_datetime,passenger_count,trip_distance,RatecodeID,store_and_fwd_flag,PULocationID,DOLocationID,payment_type,fare_amount,extra,mta_tax,tip_amount,tolls_amount,improvement_surcharge,total_amount
1,2017-07-01 00:06:25,2017-07-01 00:10:50,1,1.20,1,N,249,90,1,5.5,0.5,0.5,1.35,0,0.3,8.15
1,2017-07-01 00:20:04,2017-07-01 00:21:38,2,.20,1,N,249,158,2,3,0.5,0.5,0,0,0.3,4.3
1,2017-07-01 00:44:10,2017-07-01 00:59:29,1,4.30,1,N,100,45,1,15.5,0.5,0.5,3.35,0,0.3,20.15
1,2017-07-01 00:07:33,2017-07-01 00:31:30,1,8.30,1,N,138,162,1,27,0.5,0.5,6.8,5.76,0.3,40.86
1,2017-07-01 00:01:17,2017-07-01 00:16:18,1,1.90,1,N,107,158,1,10.5,0.5,0.5,0,0,0.3,11.8
1,2017-07-01 00:23:32,2017-07-01 00:43:23,2,4.70,1,N,158,263,1,17,0.5,0.5,3,0,0.3,21.3
1,2017-07-01 00:30:49,2017-07-01 00:46:56,3,2.30,1,N,246,162,1,12,0.5,0.5,2.65,0,0.3,15.95
1,2017-07-01 00:04:21,2017-07-01 00:25:37,1,5.40,1,N,17,90,1,19,0.5,0.5,2,0,0.3,22.3
1,2017-07-01 00:12:29,2017-07-01 00:21:54,2,1.60,1,N,170,237,2,8,0.5,0.5,0,0,0.3,9.3
1,2017-07-01 00:40:17,2017-07-01 00:56:21,3,2.60,1,N,163,90,1,12,0.5,0.5,3.3,0,0.3,16.6
1,2017-07-01 00:24:07,2017-07-01 00:28:31,1,1.10,1,N,142,143,1,5.5,0.5,0.5,1,0,0.3,7.8
1,2017-07-01 00:48:44,2017-07-01 01:13:48,1,5.90,1,N,137,17,1,21.5,0.5,0.5,4.55,0,0.3,27.3
```

---

```
public class SparkMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

public static List <String> VendorID =  Arrays.asList( "1","2");

      @Override
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       // String data = value.toString();
          int len = value.getLength();
        if (value != null &&  len > 0)
        { String[] fields = value.toString().split(",");
          String fields2 = null;
          if (fields[0] == "2" && fields[1] == "2017-10-01 00:15:30" && fields[2] == "2017-10-01 00:25:11" 
                && fields[3] == "1" && fields[4] == "2.17")
         {
            fields2= fields[0] + fields[1] +fields[2] + fields[3] + fields[4];
         }

         context.write(new Text(fields2), null);//, new Text(value));
        }

        }
}
```

```
public class SparkDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int returnStatus = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new SparkDriver(), args);
        System.exit(returnStatus);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Job job = new Job(getConf());

         job.setJobName("filter");

         job.setJarByClass(SparkDriver.class);

         job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
         job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
         job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
         job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

         job.setMapperClass(SparkMapper.class);
        // job.setReducerClass(SparkReducer.class);
    //   job.setPartitionerClass(SparkPartitioner.class);

          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));


            try {
                return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

As the file is having blank lines and header, Code is failing with Nullexecptionerror

I want to remove the header and blank spaces with successful run.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the full stack trace of the exception, including any “Caused by:” sections.  The stack trace tells you, and us, exactly where the problem is.

Comment: `if (fields[0] == "2" && fields[1] == "2017-10-01 00:15:30" && fields[2] == "2017-10-01 00:25:11" 
                && fields[3] == "1" && fields[4] == "2.17")` that is **not** how we compare `String`(s) in Java.

Comment: How can you be sure that `fields` has five elements? Your only check is that the input String isn't empty.